# What is the difference between Shimano TZ50 and Shimano RD-FT55-SS

Tags: shimano, derailleur-rear

What is the **difference** between Shimano TZ50 and Shimano RD-FT55-SS?

[Shimano RD-FT55-SS](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/tourney/RD-FT55-SS.html)

[image]

[Shimano TZ50](https://www.bankruptbikeparts.co.uk/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=20350)

[image]

I understand, that both of them a very basic.
(But it's the only options for rear derraliuer with reverse hanger.)

Comment: You linked to the product page for each derailleur, each of which has the specifications. There's your answer.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus, from what I read, I didn't notice any significant differences.

Comment: Total capacity is very different, because the TZ50 has a longer cage.

Comment: Odd - I notice BOTH of your images show a hanger claw that is reversed.  Normally the silver bolt is on the left side.  The other website states clearly "THIS WILL NOT FIT A STANDARD DROPOUT"  which is odd.   Perhaps this mech is intended for bikes with track-ends ?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus, got it!. 
I was not familiar with a **Total Capacity** concept.

Comment: @Criggie, this is exactly the type of my dropout.
It's somehow very rear and this are the only 2 types, which fit the reverse hanger for 6 speed.

Comment: @MichaelD if your bike's dropouts look like https://www.bankruptbikeparts.co.uk/image/cache/catalog/upload/PARTS/RD-TZ50/HORIZONTALA-800x600.jpg then you have "track ends" not dropouts.   There may be a different question here about "how to add gears to a bike with track ends" - if that's what your goal is, then consider asking it in a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick compare of both linked websites shows that the TZ50 is rated for a total capacity of 34 whereas the FT55 is only listed as capacity of 17.

Both are rated for a biggest big of 28 teeth, which is also their smallest big cog supported.  IE its 28 tooth only.

The FT55 has a small of 11-14 and the TZ50 has a small of 14 only.

That means the FT55 is really only intended for a 1x setup, because 28-11 is 17 which is its maximum capacity.

The TZ50 is rated to be used on both a single and double chainring.

---

Additionally, the FT55 has a pulley wheel in the rear to reduce the amount of outer cable required.  Your inner cable could be shorter and have less loop to catch on things.  All up, I suspect the FT55 is intended for folding bikes with a 1x 14-28 freewheel.

These are $10 / £10 / €10 parts.  Realistically, noone cares about weight or colour or anything at this end of the parts spectrum.  Even the orange jockey wheel is pretty irrelevant.

---

And remember Shimano's specs are very cautious.  I personally have used a TX-50 6 speed derailleur very similar to this, and it now runs an 8 speed cassette with a triple on front and the cassette ranges from 11 to 32 tooth, and works well enough.  30 tooth would have been less clattery, and I suspect 34 tooth wouldn't work at all.